# Embedding a Flutter SDK into an existing Android and IOS app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sdk, flutter-plugin

Imagine I have a big client, with a running app, with millions of users. 
This client asked me to provide him with an SDK / Plugin which he can install onto his app and use the functionality in his app.

So I'm trying to figure out, whether I can create a Flutter SDK / Plugin / Module that won't require the client to **install anything but the package** I made as if he was to NPM install this package into his app.

This should be the same for Android and IOS apps.

I read this guide https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup but I'm not sure if this requires the client to install flutter itself.

Comment: Does this mean you want to run code in an app without recompiling the app?

Comment: yes the app should be recompiled because the code has changed @JoãoSoares

Comment: Sorry. I may not be understanding what you want to achieve. You can build [iOS and Android apps native applications with Flutter added to them](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app) afterwards without needing anything else but the binary file that is output for each platform.

Comment: I mean my client does not use Flutter. he has an android native code and IOS native code. I want to create a package for him to use without having to install flutter because he already has millions of users on his app. @JoãoSoares

Comment: If you have access to the native code of each app, you should be able to create a new feature for the apps built with flutter, following the instructions I linked above.